# Casting of objects to dynamic types at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
+ (UITableViewCell *) createTableViewCell: (NSString *) cell_id withTableView: tableView {
  SomeViewClass *cell = (SomeViewClass *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cell_id];

  if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"AViewCell"
                                                             owner: nil
                                                           options: nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
      if ([currentObject isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]) {
        cell = (SomeViewClass *) currentObject;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return cell;
}
```

I'd like to abstract that code so that it can be used with any view class, not just a "SomeViewClass".  I'd like to transform it into something like the following.  Notice the cast of the dynamic type (a class *) below.

```
+ (UITableViewCell *) createTableViewCell: (NSString *) cell_id withTableView: tableView withClass: (Class) a_class {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cell_id];

  if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"AViewCell"
                                                             owner: nil
                                                           options: nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
      if ([currentObject isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]) {
        cell = (a_class *) currentObject;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return cell;
}
```

That raises a compile time error. Do I have to resort to macros? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point whatsoever in what you're trying to do, even if it were possible. That cast does not change the object, for two reasons:

1. `cell` is just an argument to the method. Reassigning `cell` to point to something else merely makes the argument point to a different object; it doesn't cause anything else in the program to change. In particular, other references to the object that `cell` originally pointed to will continue to point to that original object, blissfully unaware that the method reassigned its argument.
2. Casting a variable from `ClassA *` to `ClassB *` does not magically make the underlying data become a instance of `ClassB` — it just lies to the compiler about what kind of object the variable is pointing to. The object's class is an attribute of the object itself — that's why the `id` type is possible.

Answer (score 1):

What if you just cast it to `UITableViewCell`?

```
for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]) {
        cell = (UITableViewCell *) currentObject;
        break;
    }
}
```

That shouldn't cause any error (compile or run-time) as long as `a_class` inherits `UITableViewCell`.